# Removing EOF causing invalid syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database

How do will we get rid of the end of file error? The brackets seem valid according to ecma, unclear what's missing. Used jsonlint and found this:

```
*Error: Parse error on line 16:
...States"      }]  }]}{    "id": 1,    "name":
------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'*
```

How can we fix the error? See code below.

```js
{
//   "summersalads": [
//     {
//       "id":0,
//       "name": "Tabouli",
//       "web":"The Hungry Greek.com",
//       "description":"Crisp Romaine lettuce, with chopped cucumbers, olives, topped with Feta cheese and hummus",
//       "addresses":[
//         {
//           "addressid":"0",
//           "number":"808",
//           "line1":"N.",
//           "line2":"Franklin St",
//           "zipcode":"33602",
//           "country":"United States"
//         }
//         ]
//       }
//     ]
//   }

//     {
//   "id":1,
//   "name":"Papaya Salad",
//   "restaurant":"Ahi Asian Bistro",
//   "web":"www.ahiasianbistro.com",
//   "description":"Shrimp, green papaya, garlic, tomato, carrrot, green beans, peanut, lime juice dressing",
//   "addresses":[
//     {
//       "addressid":"1",
//       "number":"14841",
//       "line1":"N.",
//       "line2":"Dale Mabry",
//       "zipcode":"33618",
//       "country":"United States"
//     }
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a JSON file? Or what? It's not valid JSON, since it has two top-level objects. You either need an array or only one top level object. It's also not valid since only the opening bracket is uncommented.

Comment: Comments are not allowed in json

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky also true but various tooling does allow them. And without actually knowing what OP uses, it's quite hard to say whether comments can be used or not.

Comment: used solution =>      "add } to the end of your json"      it did not work

Answer (score 2):

your json is not valid. The error message shows that you need  a comma
,  between the objects,
and  move ] and add  } to the end of your json too. Your json should be

```
{
    "summersalads": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Tabouli",
            "web": "The Hungry Greek.com",
            "description": "Crisp Romaine lettuce, with chopped cucumbers, olives, topped with Feta cheese and hummus",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressid": "0",
                    "number": "808",
                    "line1": "N.",
                    "line2": "Franklin St",
                    "zipcode": "33602",
                    "country": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },          
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Papaya Salad",
            "restaurant": "Ahi Asian Bistro",
            "web": "www.ahiasianbistro.com",
            "description": "Shrimp, green papaya, garlic, tomato, carrrot, green beans, peanut, lime juice dressing",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressid": "1",
                    "number": "14841",
                    "line1": "N.",
                    "line2": "Dale Mabry",
                    "zipcode": "33618",
                    "country": "United States"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's still not valid JSON.

Comment: add } to the end of your json too

Comment: There are 5 `{` characters and 5 `}` characters. Adding one more `}` is not closing anything. It's invalid because two top-level objects are not valid.

Comment: @VLAZ See my updated answer